# Incorrect Arabic letters encoding with "kivy"

Tags: python, encoding, kivy, arabic

I am new in kivy, and initially I'd like to thank

every person that will take care of my question..

@@When I use Arabic letters in the

strings they don't apper correctly when I run the

code, although I refer to utf-8 as the encoding

at the py. or kv. files.

-My operating system is winows 7

How can I solve it?

Here is a very simple code that shows my problem:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class FirstApp(App):
     def build(self):   
        return Label(text='بسم الله')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FirstApp().run()
```

and here is the result:
[incorrect encoding result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHJ9e.jpg)

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: Kivy default font can't handle specific characters. Change `font` property of your label to a path to some `ttf` file that can handle Arabic.

Comment: @klaus D : my python is 3.4

Comment: @Nykakin: I will try this.. thanks for caring

Answer (score 2):

The documentation explains the problem and solution:

> The font kivy uses does not contain all the characters required for
> displaying all languages. When you use the built-in widgets, this
> results in a block being drawn where you expect a character.
>
> If you want to display such characters, you can chose a font that
> supports them and deploy it universally via kv:
>
> ```
> <Label>:
>     font_name: '/<path>/<to>/<font>'
> ```
>
> Note that this needs to be done before your widgets are loaded as kv
> rules are only applied at load time.

https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#catering-for-unicode-languages.

Comment: I think you save my time a lot, I will check the link and see what can be happened.. many thanks